# How to determine where a bitcoin address resides

Tags: address

I sent bitcoins to a different address that I might own. However, I am unable to determine where that bitcoin address resides. How can I determine where it resides and or how to access that bitcoin address?

Comment: It resides with the owner of the private key.  Do you have the private key?

Comment: What do you mean by where it resides? If you mean who can redeem the bitcoins you have sent to the address, it will be, as @BrettDoffing said, the owner of the private key. Which kind of wallet are you using? Does the address to where you send the transaction show up in the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

You cant. You can send BTC to anywhere, including addresses that will never exist.

If you're reasonably sure that the address is in use, i.e. by seeing active transactions on bitcoin.info, you could try sending a small transaction with a message in it, but it will likely be ignored.

In all probability, you lost these coins.